# How to check if task output list contains a string using filter or JMESPath?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, jmespath

I am writing a simple Ansible playbook (Ansible version - 2.9) to start a service and then want to extract certain fields – "changed" and "failed" – from the output for debugging purpose

These are my tasks:

```yaml
- name: Start service if stopped
  command: systemctl start confluent-*
  register: confluent_start_status
  ignore_errors: true

- debug:
    var: "{{ confluent_start_status.cmd| json_query([?contains(@,'start') == 'true']) }}"
```

And this is the output of the start task.

```json
{
    "confluent_start_status": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "systemctl",
            "start",
            "confluent-*"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:01.425703",
        "end": "2023-01-31 14:14:22.567335",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2023-01-31 14:14:21.141632",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```

How can I check that the `cmd` list contains the string `start` and assign `true` to a variable if it does?
Basically I want to create a variable using `set_fact`, when `changed` is `true`, `failed` is `false` and `cmd` contains `start`, to use it in the next task.

Comment: _and then want to extract certain fields_ > what fields are you looking for here, you didn't stated that in you question?

Comment: "changed" and "failed" - Also updated the question.  Basically I want to create a variable using set_fact - when "changed" is true, "failed" is false and cmd contains "start"  -  to use it in the next tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I check that the `cmd` list contains the string `start` and assign `true` to a variable if it does?

With JMESPath:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    is_start: >-
      {{ 
        confluent_start_status 
          | json_query('contains(cmd, `start`)') 
      }}
```

With plain Jinja:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    is_start: "{{ 'start' in confluent_start_status.cmd }}"
```

---

As for your requirements to combine the facts that the task should raise a changed state, should not have failed and that the `cmd` should contain `start`, there are also [tests for tasks results](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results) that makes is more human readable:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    confluence_task_status: >-
      {{
        'start' in confluent_start_status.cmd
        and confluent_start_status is changed
        and confluent_start_status is not failed
      }}
```

Comment: Is one approach preferable over the other in Ansible Playbook - Jinja vs. JMESPath?

Comment: If you don't need JMESPath, then, no need to bother with it (it is an extra lib, but if you have it installed already, fine). And honestly for such a "simple" requirement, the Jinja syntax is way more readable, but that is just my point of view.

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying with JMESPath because those were some examples I saw and was trying to fit them to my requirement.  But agree that Jinja is more readable.  Will use the Jinja style for my purpose.  Also, can I combine the 3 tests - the cmd as above AND  confluent_start_status.changed == 'True' AND confluent_start_status.failed == 'False' in one line to set_fact is_success ?

Comment: Yes, there are also tests to make that human readable. See edit.